# How to randomly select a row from the database in Android Studio?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am currently working on a simple android quiz app.

The code is as follows:

```
package com.example.darel.geogame;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class QuizHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mathsone";
    // tasks table name
    private static final String TABLE_QUEST = "quest";
    // tasks Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "qid";
    private static final String KEY_QUES = "question";
    private static final String KEY_ANSWER = "answer"; // correct option
    private static final String KEY_OPTA = "opta"; // option a
    private static final String KEY_OPTB = "optb"; // option b
    private static final String KEY_OPTC = "optc"; // option c
    private SQLiteDatabase dbase;
    public QuizHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        dbase = db;
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST + " ( "
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_QUES
                + " TEXT, " + KEY_ANSWER + " TEXT, " + KEY_OPTA + " TEXT, "
                + KEY_OPTB + " TEXT, " + KEY_OPTC + " TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(sql);
        addQuestion();
// db.close();
    }
    private void addQuestion() {
        Question q1 = new Question("5+2 = ?", "7", "8", "6", "7");
        this.addQuestion(q1);
        Question q2 = new Question("2+18 = ?", "18", "19", "20", "20");
        this.addQuestion(q2);
        Question q3 = new Question("10-3 = ?", "6", "7", "8", "7");
        this.addQuestion(q3);
        Question q4 = new Question("5+7 = ?", "12", "13", "14", "12");
        this.addQuestion(q4);
        Question q5 = new Question("3-1 = ?", "1", "3", "2", "2");
        this.addQuestion(q5);
        Question q6 = new Question("0+1 = ?", "1", "0", "10", "1");
        this.addQuestion(q6);
        Question q7 = new Question("9-9 = ?", "0", "9", "1", "0");
        this.addQuestion(q7);
        Question q8 = new Question("3+6 = ?", "8", "7", "9", "9");
        this.addQuestion(q8);
        Question q9 = new Question("1+5 = ?", "6", "7", "5", "6");
        this.addQuestion(q9);
        Question q10 = new Question("7-5 = ?", "3", "2", "6", "2");
        this.addQuestion(q10);
        Question q11 = new Question("7-2 = ?", "7", "6", "5", "5");
        this.addQuestion(q11);
        Question q12 = new Question("3+5 = ?", "8", "7", "5", "8");
        this.addQuestion(q12);
        Question q13 = new Question("0+6 = ?", "7", "6", "5", "6");
        this.addQuestion(q13);
        Question q14 = new Question("12-10 = ?", "1", "2", "3", "2");
        this.addQuestion(q14);
        Question q15 = new Question("12+2 = ?", "14", "15", "16", "14");
        this.addQuestion(q15);
        Question q16 = new Question("2-1 = ?", "2", "1", "0", "1");
        this.addQuestion(q16);
        Question q17 = new Question("6-6 = ?", "6", "12", "0", "0");
        this.addQuestion(q17);
        Question q18 = new Question("5-1 = ?", "4", "3", "2", "4");
        this.addQuestion(q18);
        Question q19 = new Question("4+2 = ?", "6", "7", "5", "6");
        this.addQuestion(q19);
        Question q20 = new Question("5+1 = ?", "6", "7", "5", "6");
        this.addQuestion(q20);
        Question q21 = new Question("5-4 = ?", "5", "4", "1", "1");
        this.addQuestion(q21);
// END
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldV, int newV) {
// Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST);
// Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }
    // Adding new question
    public void addQuestion(Question quest) {
// SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_QUES, quest.getQUESTION());
        values.put(KEY_ANSWER, quest.getANSWER());
        values.put(KEY_OPTA, quest.getOPTA());
        values.put(KEY_OPTB, quest.getOPTB());
        values.put(KEY_OPTC, quest.getOPTC());
// Inserting Row
        dbase.insert(TABLE_QUEST, null, values);
    }
    public List<Question> getAllQuestions() {
        List<Question> quesList = new ArrayList<Question>();
// Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_QUEST;
        dbase = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = dbase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
// looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Question quest = new Question();
                quest.setID(cursor.getInt(0));
                quest.setQUESTION(cursor.getString(1));
                quest.setANSWER(cursor.getString(2));
                quest.setOPTA(cursor.getString(3));
                quest.setOPTB(cursor.getString(4));
                quest.setOPTC(cursor.getString(5));
                quesList.add(quest);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
// return quest list
        return quesList;
    }
}
```

According to the above code, the app is listing the questions in order of the code written.
I want the app to randomly select a question instead of in order without repeating.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

`According to the above code, the app is listing the questions in order of the code written.` **Wrong**.

You are never granted in which order your rows will be fetched from a table.
This is why the `ORDER BY` clause exists.

Along with its various modifiers (`ASC`, `DESC`) you can also use `RANDOM()`, which shuffles the row set.

Therefore, instead of

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_QUEST;
```

use

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_QUEST + " ORDER BY RANDOM()";
```

If you need a **single** question, you can use

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_QUEST + " ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1";
```

But this won't grant that the next time you execute the query you won't see the same row again.

Therefore, I'd fetch all the rows at once and consume the cursor one row at a time.